# How to Check Time Between Specific DateTime in Sql Server

Tags: sql, datetime, datediff

I have a table name `PrayerTimes`. I want to get next coming Prayer Time. There is Break in each and every Prayer. Like 30 minutes or 35 minutes. How i can check that this is Prayer Break time.

As i attached images that are showing that till 5:01AM. It's showing me next prayer time so i can get break time as well. But at 5:02AM it is showing next prayer time.

Here is Sample

```
 id         Time                        Break_Time
 1          2016-10-20 05:03:00.000     2016-10-20 05:33:00.000
 2          2016-10-20 12:06:00.000     2016-10-20 12:36:00.000
 3          2016-10-20 15:25:00.000     2016-10-20 15:31:00.000
 4          2016-10-20 17:53:00.000     2016-10-20 18:23:00.000
 5          2016-10-20 19:23:00.000     2016-10-20 19:53:00.000
 6          2016-10-21 05:03:00.000     2016-10-21 05:33:00.000
 7          2016-10-21 12:06:00.000     2016-10-21 12:36:00.000
 8          2016-10-21 15:24:00.000     2016-10-21 15:54:00.000
 9          2016-10-21 17:52:00.000     2016-10-21 18:22:00.000
 10         2016-10-21 19:22:00.000     2016-10-21 19:52:00.000
```

I want to return `True` if Time is Between Time and Break_Time

Comment: Can you post some sample input and desired output rather than images.... Use Ctrl K to arrange your input and output...

Comment: @Teja, Please check Edited Post now

Comment: Can you post desired output as well.... If the input and output are clear then its easy to solve any problem..

Comment: @Teja, I want to check this table and if the date is between Time and Break_Time is should return True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top 1 [Time] from prayertimes where SYSDATETIME() < DateAdd(minute, 30, [time]) order by [time]
```